# Modify expect-based SSH script to work on machines that don't require a password

Tags: linux, tcl, ksh, expect

The following expect script works fine when the Linux machine asks for a password after login. But some of our Linux machines don't need a password for SSH (we can login without a password), so I need to change the expect script in order to support machines without a password. How can I do that?

```
$ expect_test=`cat << EOF
set timeout -1
spawn  ssh $IP  hostname
    expect {
              ")?"   { send "yes\r"  ; exp_continue  }
              word:  {send "pass123\r"     }
    }
expect eof
EOF`

$ expect -c "$expect_test"
```

When running on a machine that needs a password:

```
 $ IP=10.17.18.6
 $ expect -c "$expect_test"
 spawn ssh 10.17.18.6 hostname
 sh: /usr/local/bin/stty: not found
 This computer system, including all related equipment, networks and network devices     (specifically including Internet access),is pros
 yes
 Password: 
 Linux1_machine
```

When running on a machine that doesn't need a password:

```
$ IP=10.10.92.26
$ expect -c "$expect_test"
spawn ssh 10.10.92.26 hostname
sh: /usr/local/bin/stty: not found
Linux15_machine
expect: spawn id exp5 not open
while executing
"expect eof"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this expect command:

```
expect {
    ")?"   {send "yes\r";     exp_continue}
    word:  {send "pass123\r"; exp_continue}
    eof
}
```

That way, if EOF is encountered before "password:", the script will act normally.

Comment: You might decide to only send the password once. Luckily, that's easy to enforce with a little extra logic.

Answer (score 0):

Change you timeout from -1 to something else, this will cause expect to move on to the next line if the expected string does not show up within the given timeout.

The current value, -1 causes it to block forever if not password is prompted for.

**UPDATE:**

```
 set timeout 5
 spawn  ssh $IP  hostname
       expect {
                 ")?"   { send "yes\r"  ; exp_continue  }
                 word:  {send "pass123\r"     }
                 eof    {exit}
      }
```

Comment: I set it to 10 but still I get the error -->  expect: spawn id exp5 not open  while executing  "expect eof"

Comment: Add exp_internal 1 right above the timeout line in the script and see what it outputs. Also add eof { exit } inside the first expect part, on a new line under the one with word:

Comment: not clearly where to add the "eof" can you update my script with the addtional eof ?